# accessing http invoker service from a test client protected by spring security in spring remoting

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-remoting

I have an spring remoting implemented via HttpInvoker .
My client and service looks like below taken from spring docs I followed the spring doc: (sorry I could not post actual code due to company policy)[=>spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html)

My httInvoker service is protected by spring security and on the client side I have following client code along with httpinvokerrequestexecutor as below:

```
    <bean id="httpProxybean" class="org.springframework....HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean>
    <property name=".." ref="executor"/>
<property name="service"...
</bean>

    <bean id="executor" class='org......HttpInvokerRequestExecutor/>
```

The problem I have is when I am trying to test the service from the test client as below: I get...... *unable to connect to http remote service : 401 unuthorized*

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    Application context = new XmlPathApplicationContext("client.xml");
Service service =(Service) context.getBean("service");
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong, I am assuming I am getting that because of the HttpInvokerRequestExecutor. Now when I try to pass username and password as below : I took it from an example . I am still getting the same error *unable to connect to http remote service : 401 unuthorized* . 
 It works fine when I remove the HttpInvokerRequestExecutor and disable intercept-url for the services.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    final ApplicationContext context =

new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(

"client/spring-http-client-config.xml");

String user = "bob";

String pw = "bob";

SecurityContextImpl sc = new SecurityContextImpl();

Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,

pw);



sc.setAuthentication(auth);

SecurityContextHolder.setContext(sc);


    Service service =(Service) context.getBean("service");
    }
```

The security config xml is configured for test purpose is

```
<authenticationManager>
.....................
<user username="bob" password="bob" authorities ="ROLE_ADMIN">
..........................
</authenticationManager>
```

and intercept url is 
`<intercept-url path="/remoting/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`.
Now questions:
i. When testing a client how do I pass credentials from client to the server? Remember my services are protected by spring security so I want to pass the Security context from client to server so that server can authenticate it. 
ii. When testing I can access the services if I remove the HttpInvokerRequestExecutor and in the server side , I disable the intercept-url filter for accessing the services.
I would really appreciate your help on this. I have been looking for a solution
iii. Please give me some idea on how to pass credentials from client side to server side and if this is possible while testing?

Comment: What authentication method are you using on the server side? Like HTTP Basic?

Comment: Yes spring http basic authentication

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/remoting/httpinvoker/AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.html).

(If you use maven this is found in the `spring-security-remoting` dependency.)

It will pick authentication information from `SecurityContextHolder`.